# Porting Makefile to Jenkinsfile, but having problems with environment variables

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to port a Makefile that is used to build the project locally into an automated build system in Jenkins. This Makefile uses docker containers to build the project. However I'm open to suggestions as to how to make the entire structure as I have no clue what I'm doing!

I'm wondering how I can port this kind of snippet:

```
PKGS       = $(shell go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/ | grep -v /bindata)
VERSION    = $(shell git describe)
VERSION64  = $(shell git describe | base64)
SHA        = $(shell git rev-parse HEAD)
PWD        = $(shell pwd)
```

Into a declarative pipeline. When I wrap the variables on an `environment` block, I get this:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 10: unexpected token: list @ line 10, column 30.
             PKGS        = $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/ | grep -v /bindata)
                                ^

1 error
```

The way I'm starting the pipeline is such as this (and after the first stage, I declare the env vars):

```java
pipeline {
    agent {
      docker {
        image 'golang:1.11'
        args '-v $(PWD):/go/src/project -w /go/src/project'
      }
    }
```

Comment: The equivalent of `shell` is the `sh` step which you could call like this from a `script` block: `VERSION = sh script: 'git describe', returnStdout: true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Zett42 commented, you could set the environment variables as below in Jenkins pipeline. You can find more info on https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'golang:1.11'
      args '-v $(PWD):/go/src/project -w /go/src/project'
    }
  } 
  environment {
    // Using returnStdout
    VERSION = """${sh(
      returnStdout: true,
      script: 'git describe'
    )}""" 
    //Here you can include other env like above..   
  }
  stages {
    stage('Example') {
      environment {
        DEBUG_FLAGS = '-g'
      }
      steps {
        sh 'printenv'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The code can be simplified like this: `environment{ VERSION = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git describe').trim() }`. There is no need to wrap the call in triple-double-quoted string.